# How do I configure My AWS Lambda to take input parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I want my AWS Lambda function to take a input parameter. Example- the parameter is a date and I want to update a field in the Database using that Date. How do I get that date to my Lambda ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda's can get params from 2 sources:

- triggering event
- env variables

Adding environment variables is independent of the triggering event, but it doesn't change value between invocation.

Adding fields to the triggering event depends heavily on the type of event and should be handled on the side of the event's source.

Comment: Also one more way to pass input to your lambda that i found was triggering your lambda using cloudwatch event and passing your custom JSON..the cloudwatch will trigger the lambda and pass your custom JSON as event to lambda.